# Event ID 9175 but no exchange server in the environment

Tags: exchange

I'm running DCDiag command on windows server 2003 and im getting error related to Event ID 9175, when i try to search for a solution, it says it is related to exchange server database, while actually we don't have Exchange Server in our environment

what could be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: okey, currently we are planning to upgrade our Active Directory from windows server 2003 to windows server 2012,
it was advised as a 1st step to check the current environment health by running the command DCDIAG and try to sole any reported issues.
I ran th e command and one of the issues was that event 9175 and when i ried to search what is that, i found out it is related to exchange server, but actually we dont have exchange server in our environment, so what could be the issue generated such an event log

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the value of "Disable MAPI client" key in registry if there it is under:
Hkey Local\system\currentcontrolset\services\MsExchangeIS\ParametersSystem\Disable MAPI client

Comment: this value "Disable MAPI client" is not exist in the mentioned registry path i can only see the values:
"Circular Logging", 
"DB Recovery", 
"DSA Computer",
"MTA Computer", 
"Online Compaction", 
"Rpc/HTTP Port", 
"This Server", 
"Working Directory",

and in the working directory it has the value "C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\MDBDATA"
while as i mentioned we dont have exchange server in our environment, or actually there was exchange installed before then was uninstalled long time back